# Text Alignment in paragraph box

Tags: horizontal-alignment, pstricks, text-manipulation

I'm writing graphic application to generate latex tex. I'm making to generate text box with all it's features. Rotation alignment so on. I generated following cording but It was not Right aligned properly in paragrah box I have shown bounding box. What is wrong there...

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{pstricks}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[arabic,english]{babel}

\begin{document}

\textLR{
\begin{pspicture}(10, 10)
\psgrid
\definecolor{Black}{RGB}{0,0,0}
\rput{0}(3.9,7){%
\psframe[,linestyle=solid,linewidth=0.265mm,linecolor=Black](-2.1,1.9)(2.1,-1.9)
\uput{0.01cm}[320]{0}(-2.1,1.9){%
\parbox[t][3.8cm][t]{4cm}{
\color[rgb]{0,0,0}
\scriptsize
\begin{flushright}
Right Aligned
\newline Right Aligned
\newline Right Aligned
\newline Right Aligned
\newline Right Aligned
\newline Right Aligned
\newline Right Aligned
\newline Right Aligned
\newline Right Aligned
\newline\end{flushright}
}
}
}
\end{pspicture}}

\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)

Comment: for some reason, the bounding box doesn't show up for me.  adding `\null\hfill` to the beginning of one line and `\hfill\null` to the end of another does show that everything else is centered.  but why that is happening is a mystery to me.

Answer (score 3):

`flushright` environment calls `\raggedleft` which locally redefines `\\` to make a ragged break, but it does not redefine `\newline`. If you change all your `\newline` to `\\` the text goes to the right edge of the box.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.The Problem solved.But always I got error indicating "!Latex Error : There is no line here to end". Why that is showing.

Comment: @TextAlignment That usually means you have `\\ ` at the _start_ of a paragraph you can't force a line break when you have not started a line yet.

Comment: \parbox[t][3.8cm][t]{4cm}{
    \color[rgb]{0,0,0}
    \scriptsize
    \raggedleft
    \\ Right Aligned Text
    \\ Right Aligned Text
    }
Appreciate your quick response. If I do like this \\  in beginning of line paragraph. Generate same error.

Comment: well there you have `\\ ` before `Right Aligned Text` which is an error. Also you will get the alignment wrong if you start with `\color` at the start of a `\parbox` use `\mbox{}\color` for technical reasons explained in the grfguide documentation that comes with latex.